# StackExchange inbox tab shows only older messages

Tags: bug, status-completed, global-inbox

The StackExchange Inbox tab (not the top left inbox link but the dedicated page) has been stuck on older messages for  <strike>around 2</strike> around **4** days now.

Scroll down from top left Inbox to the bottom to "See All". This link sometimes shows as "*more inbox messages …"*

[image]

which takes you to the page below. Note: you can get to this Inbox page from `Network Profile > Inbox` as well

Mine is **out of sync by about 40 messages** or 12 days. In case that helps.

[image]

Comment: Wow, I've never notice the "See all" link, and don't see it currently (IE9).

Comment: @Lance: I've tried IE8 and FF5 and can "See All". Besides you can get to this Inbox page from **Network Profile > Inbox** too.

Comment: @Lance: Did you scroll down to the bottom of the inbox? There's the link.

Comment: OK, I see it after scrolling, but it says __"more inbox messages ...".__  My last message was Sep 14th it says, so yeh, I'm missing a weeks worth.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was an ordering issue here, your new items were actually on page 2, 3, 4, or 5 (depending on how many you had).  This is now fixed.

---

In-depth why, *because we care* <3:
We actually store your inbox in 2 places, your most recent items are in [redis](http://redis.io/), and your older ones are in SQL.  After a small delay a background process culls them from redis to SQL.

Actually after a minute or two usually, all your items are in both places...but since redis may still be changing, or have a deletion that's not yet persisted, etc...we need to construct the *overall* inbox that stackexchange.com shows from both sources.

To do this, we take the items from redis (observing the earliest date) and the items from SQL (any before the minimum redis date), then combine them in code [via `.Union()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341731.aspx), *this was happening backwards in some cases*.

In addition to that, the API on the backend for has a page size 5x larger than what is shown on stackexchange.com (meaning se.com loads 5 pages at once when fetching)...combine these two and you see how your new items were appearing at the end of the first API page, which translated to anywhere from page 1-5 on stackexchange.com, depending on how many new items you had.

Comment: didnt expect this to be fixed on the weekend, cheers